# how to install a visualfox pro odbc on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, odbc, ole

I'm currently on a windows 7 laptop, on which I want to install a visualfoxpro driver.

On Microsoft's [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490121.aspx), it says Visualfoxpro's ODBC driver has been discontinued.

I've used instead `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0 SP2`.
I thought mistakenly this should give me an OLE driver through `odbcad32` . Yet after the install, when I'm trying to add any driver with `odbacad32`, there are no visualfoxpro drivers (see below)

[image]

Any tips are more than welcomed as I'm losing my sanity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had exactly the same issue a couple of years ago...

There are 2 versions of odbcad32 on a 64-bit Windows system. And they are both called odbcad**32**.
The default version is the 64-bit version, which will only work for 64-bit ODBC drivers.
You must use the 32 bit version because the FoxPro ODBC drivers are 32 bit only. (And only work together with 32-applications...)
The 32-bit version is in c:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Comment: hey @Tonny, you're the man. Esta grgrhh de Windows ...